# Bing Maps for Enterprise - URL Referrer

Tags: azure, bing-maps

Our company is about to launch a web page to production using Bing Maps for Enterprise. There is a setting that should be available, but I'm not finding this setting, URL referrer. This setting is easy to find in the Bing Dev Center on my personal account, but I'm not finding this setting in my company's Azure Portal. Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Microsoft via Azure support request. The URL referrer (whitelisting) option is not available in Azure - Bing Maps API for Enterprise as of 4/28/2020. This is the response received from Microsoft, Bing Maps Enterprise Support.

Tuesday, April 28, 2020 1:21 PM:

Issue Description:  Customer is inquiring about adding key whitelisting to their Bing Maps keys
Scope Agreement:  As per your communication, you are inquiring about adding key whitelisting to your Bing Maps keys

Currently, the key whitelisting feature outlined in that blog is only available on keys created through www.bingmapsportal.com.  We will submit a feature request to have this added to keys created through the Bing Maps Azure resource, so it will be considered in future updates.